# Sticky MAC - Not working/appearing in run config?

Tags: cisco, port-security

Running  3 x 3850's stacked.

On some interfaces I run the following commands:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
description Servers
switchport access vlan 50
switchport mode access
switchport port-security mac-address sticky
ip access-group xxxxxx in
spanning-tree bpduguard enable
```

However I can plug other devices in and they gain connectivity and "Learnt" MAC address does not appear in running-config.

It doesn`t appear to be implementing Stick MAC successfully.

This appears to be sue to port security not working as per output of:

```
CABA_SW#show port-security int g 1/0/1
Port Security              : Disabled
Port Status                : Secure-down
Violation Mode             : Shutdown
Aging Time                 : 0 mins
Aging Type                 : Absolute
SecureStatic Address Aging : Disabled
Maximum MAC Addresses      : 1
Total MAC Addresses        : 0
Configured MAC Addresses   : 0
Sticky MAC Addresses       : 0
Last Source Address:Vlan   : 0000.0000.0000:0
Security Violation Count   : 0
```

I thought the command "switchport port-security mac-address sticky" 
would enable port security?

IOS:

```
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 16.06.01
Cisco IOS Software [Everest], Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT3K_CAA-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 16.6.1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
```

Any suggestions?

Regards

Aidan

Comment: You need `switchport port-security` command to activate port-security on a port.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to enter the "switch port-security" command so it would look like this:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 description Servers
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport mode access
 switchport port-security
 switchport port-security mac-address sticky
 ip access-group xxxxxx in
 spanning-tree bpduguard enable
```

Thanks

Aidan